# Is there any alternatives in GWT for the javascript getElementsByClassName function?

Tags: javascript, dom, gwt

I know to select an Id in GWT we use

`DOM.getElementById`
same like javascript, but is there a way to make use for Classes like

```
DOM.getElementsByClassName
```

Comment: You do know that Java is a completly different language than javascript or GWT, right?

Comment: You could also use [GWTQuery](https://github.com/gwtquery/), which simulates jQuery.